# Can't run two RFID readers off the same 5V rail

Tags: arduino, rfid, decoupling-capacitor

I have a circuit consisting of an Arduino Mega2560 connected to a 134.2kHz RFID reader from [Priority1Design](http://www.priority1design.com.au/shopfront/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1&products_id=4). The RFID reader works fine by itself, however as soon as other components are connected to the 5V rail it stops reading data.

I've done some measurements and the current going to the reader does not ever exceed 35mA and the voltage sits around 5V. When another component is connected to 5V and GND (say, another one of the same RFID readers without Tx and Rx connected), the voltage over the original RFID reader drops by about 50mV and the current remains the same (the Mega can provide more than enough current for both of the RFID readers).

I've performed some experiments where I try reading with both readers connected, then I unplug the second one and the first one will start reading again. I've also tried connecting decoupling capacitors between the 5V and GND pins of each of the readers (as close to the reader as possible), but nothing changed.

Here's a schematic of the effective circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmkcfX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When SW1 is open, RFID1 reads properly. When SW1 is closed, it cannot read. I've also noticed that when I probe Tx or Rx with an oscilloscope, it cannot read anything either.

If anyone has any suggestions as to how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your schematic, the node tagged 'GND RFID2' is not connected to ground, it's connected directly to 5V. Assuming this is just a goof in the schematic here, you should double check the connections to the RFID module to make sure you're not accidentally shorting the circuit through it or something.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks for spotting that. `GND RFID2` should be connected to the GND rail. I'll update the schematic ASAP

Comment: Where does the 5V power supply come from(I assume USB connected to your pc/laptop, which might be the cause of all your problems) ? Do you have a more detailed schematic?

Comment: Try separating the readers spatially and see if it alters the result. The dvice presumably has onboard processor and TX oscillator. Also try a series resistance on the psu side of the cap in each case. At 35 mA a 1k drops 35 mV and a 19k 350 mV. The higher R the batter that is tolerated.  Note that in [the datasheet](http://www.priority1design.com.au/rfidread-mrw.pdf) they say: "The effects of noise on the RFIDREAD-μRW.
Reading a passive RFID transponder requires a sensitive receiver to read the data over the reading distance
of the tag. ...

Comment: ... As this requires detecting minute signals any electrical noise in the environment will affect read
range.


 It is advisable to use a well regulated voltage supply free of additional noise otherwise read and write
range can be drastically reduced. In addition the presence of noisy electronics such as high speed
microprocessors, switch mode power supplies, or signals from other noisy sources such as USB interfaces
will also impact the readers performance.

Comment: What is the distance between both readers? Are you sure they don't interfere with each other?

Comment: @RubenDefour It is being powered by a 12V wall wart, but is also connected to the PC via USB. I've noticed the range of the RFID is longer using the 12V supply (not sure why, as only 5V is being supplied to the reader)

Comment: @RusselMcMahon The readers were quite close, but I didn't think they'd interfere since only one of them was actively trying to read a tag. However, I moved them apart and it seems to work. Strangely, turning off the 12V supply connected to the Arduino causes it to not read at all, even when they are separated